# iOS DHCP Request

Tags: ios, dhcp

I have observed from a wireless packet capture in my home network that anytime my iPhone device switches from asleep to active, and it is not attached to a power source, it sends a DHCP Request. I have validated this behavior with two different iPhones (with different iOS versions). I have also tested an Android device and this does not happen.

Hence this makes me wonder why does an iPhone need to send a DHCP Request, once switched from asleep to active, if the DHCP lease has not expired? In addition, why doesn't this happen in an Android device?

I am pretty sure this is not an issue related to a bug, such as the one reported in
http://www.net.princeton.edu/apple-ios/ios41-allows-lease-to-expire-keeps-using-IP-address.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device thinks it has an unexpired lease, and the device's network interface has just brought up physical LINK, then that the client should start in the DHCP INIT-REBOOT state (or even INIT state).

Alternatively, if the device thinks it has an unexpired lease, and has kept LINK *up* continuously since going to sleep, then the client could start in the BOUND state when awaking.

Basically the main reason that the devices react differently is the way they handle the sleep mode (most iOS will disable the wireless interface, whereas in Android it is configurable in the menu).